# Inject specific dependency based on its consumer / context dependency with Unity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, nlog

I am using `Nlog` as a logging framework in my Web API project with `Unity` an s IoC container.

I have `LoggingService` class which takes the class name as an argument and return an instance of NLog. For this, I have used dependency injection.

**Question** : I am rather confused about how can I pass the class name to my `LoggingService` class?

Code:

```cs
using NLog;

namespace Portal.Util.Logging
{
    public class LoggingService : ILoggingService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public LoggingService(string currentClassName)
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(currentClassName);
        }

        public void FirstLevelServiceLog(string log)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, log);
        }
    }

    public interface ILoggingService
    {
        void FirstLevelServiceLog(string log);
    }
}
```

Service Layer: (This is being called from Controller)

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

    public MyService(ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        _loggingService = loggingService
    }

    public DoSomething()
    {
        _loggingService.FirstLevelServiceLog("Debug");
    }
}
```

Unity:

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>(new InjectionConstructor("")) 
/* Not sure on how to pass the class name here? */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a design issue masked behind an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The logging service is in need of some refactoring to make it easier to inject the desired behavior.

introduce an additional generic interface that is derived from the base `ILoggingService`

```cs
public interface ILoggingService<TType> : ILoggingService {

}

public interface ILoggingService {
    void FirstLevelServiceLog(string log);
}
```

refactor the current implementation to depend on the generic version of the service

```cs
public class LoggingService<TType> : ILoggingService<TType> {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingService() {
        string currentClassName = typeof(TType).Name;
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(currentClassName);
    }

    public void FirstLevelServiceLog(string log) {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, log);
    }
}
```

This would allow the type argument to be used to determine the name of the class for the log manager

Now those dependent on the logging service can be explicit about their dependency via constructor injection

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

    public MyService(ILoggingService<MyService> loggingService) {
        _loggingService = loggingService
    }

    public DoSomething() {
        _loggingService.FirstLevelServiceLog("Debug");
    }
}
```

Note how the only thing that was needed to be refactored was the generic argument for the constructor as the generic logger is derived from the base `ILoggingService`.

The logging service abstraction can finally be registered using open generics for its implementation

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();    
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILoggingService<>), typeof(LoggingService<>));
```

That way there is no need to register a separate implementation for each logger used in the system.

Answer (score 0):

One ways to do this is using Registration By Name.

You first register all your loggers and give each logger it's name.

You use an `InjectionConstructor` for injection the param value.

```
var ctr = new UnityContainer();

// You can add lifetimemanagers as well
ctr.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>("Class1Logger",new InjectionConstructor("Class1"));
ctr.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>("Class2Logger", new InjectionConstructor("Class2"));
```

Then you create you logical classes by injecting by name (using the `Dependency` attribute):

```
public class MyLogic1
{
    public MyLogic1([Dependency("Class1Logger")]ILoggingService logger)
    {

    }
}

public class MyLogic2
{
    public MyLogic2([Dependency("Class2Logger")]ILoggingService logger)
    {

    }
}
```

And that's all you need to do.

I usually think that registering by name isn't really the best practice and I most of the time prefer some kind of dummy interface inheritance (since I don't like to map the same interface type to concrete types). 
But in this case, it looks like a decent & clean approach to solve the problem.

If you want automatic registration, you can use some kind of reflection (custom attribute or based on implementation of `ILogger`) and register all of your instances automatically.